# String interpolation: How do I make this function work with any type

Tags: c#, .net, generics, iterator, func

This is a function to work with lists in string interpolation. It takes a List and an inner Func, and it appends the string result of the inner Func called for each member of the list, with a separator.

So the following builds a valid start of an Insert statement...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tableName = "customers";
    var cols = new List<dynamic>
    {
        new { Name = "surname"},
        new { Name = "firstname"},
        new { Name = "dateOfBirth"}
    };
    Func<List<dynamic>, Func<dynamic, string>, string, string> ForEach = (list, func, separator) =>
        {
            var bldr = new StringBuilder();
            var first = true;
            foreach (var obj in list)
            {
                if (!first)
                    bldr.Append(separator);
                first = false;
                bldr.Append(func(obj));
            }
            return bldr.ToString();
        };

    var InsertStatement = $"Insert into { tableName } ( {ForEach(cols, col => col.Name, ", ")} )";
    Console.WriteLine(InsertStatement);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Outputs...

```
Insert into customers ( surname, firstname, dateOfBirth )
```

It works for dynamic. How do I make it work for any type? The outer Func shouldn't care about the Type in the list, it just passes it through to the inner Func.

Comment: You can make `ForEach` method generic and apply some constraints on it

Comment: `List<T>` already has a `ForEach` method built in. Also, you're practically inviting hackers constructing SQL this way. Read about SQL Injection.

Comment: You've also passed the list of objects in outer `Func` and inner `Func` to access these objects members, both functions should care about the type, otherwise `dynamic` is only option here

Comment: As an aside, `string.Join(separator, list.Select(func))` means you don't need to write your own code for that...

Comment: `var query = $"INSERT INTO {tableName}({string.Join(",", cols.Select(x=>x.Name))})";`

Comment: Do you really need an array of anonymous object having Name property for column? Wouldn't a `string[]` enough?

Comment: If for learning purpose you like to write a generic version, write a new method, you cannot do it using `Func`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled You probably don't mean, but your comment is saying generating SQL statement is a risk; however, generating a sql statement at run-time doesn't equals to opening SQL Injection door for attackers. For the OP, it's just the first part of the insert query, for the next part, OP should consider generating parameters, like `VALUES(@surname, @firstname, @dateOfBirth)`

Comment: @RezaAghaei Well, generating SQL statements dynamically **might** be a risk; if getting the identifiers from the user, or forgetting to parameterize data - than yes, it is a risk. Dynamic SQL should be considered as a potential risk, and this is what I actually mean - but as a comment to the OP, that seemed to me like too much to write at that point. If you're interested, check out my blog post called [The do's and don'ts of dynamic SQL for SQL Server](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/09/12/the-does-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql-for-sql-server/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET framework already gives you a generic function to achieve what you are trying to do [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) and you can combine it with a LINQ Select statement, which will allow you to use a lambda on a generic type to select the property that you want to print. You can view the source code of these methods if you are interested as they are open source.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class MyType
{
   public string Name { get; set; } 
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var tableName = "customers";
        var cols = new List<MyType>
        {
            new MyType { Name = "surname"},
            new MyType { Name = "firstname"},
            new MyType { Name = "dateOfBirth"}
        };

        var InsertStatement = $"Insert into { tableName } ( {String.Join(", ", cols.Select(col => col.Name))} )";
        Console.WriteLine(InsertStatement);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `dynamic` with `object`, or `TValue` with a type constraint stipulating it must be a class (`where TValue : class`), and call `obj.ToString()` instead of just `obj`

However, this doesn't guarantee it would "work with any type" - for that you need to know that those types all follow a contract to output the desired column name as their string representation. To get more specificity, require that your accepted types must implement some interface eg `IColumnName` and put that interface into the type constraint instead

Comment: OP wants to access an object members, using inner `Func`, `ToString()` doesn't work here, IMO

Answer (score 0):

You can create the text easily like this:

```
var query = $"INSERT INTO {tableName}({string.Join(",", cols.Select(x=>x.Name))})";
```

However, if **for learning purpose** you are going to handle the case using a generic method, you can create a generic function like the following and then easily use a `for` loop and strip additional separator using `TrimEnd`, or as a better option, like [`String.Join` implementation of .NET Framework](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,fa961ce440526a4d) get enumerator like this:

```
string Join<TItem>(
    IEnumerable<TItem> items, Func<TItem, string> itemTextSelecor, string separator)
{
    var en = items.GetEnumerator();
    if (!en.MoveNext())
        return String.Empty;
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (en.Current != null)
        builder.Append(itemTextSelecor(en.Current));
    while (en.MoveNext())
    {
        builder.Append(separator);
        if (en.Current != null)
            builder.Append(itemTextSelecor(en.Current));
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

And use it this way:

```
var tableName = "customers";
var cols = new[]
{
    new { Name = "surname"},
    new { Name = "firstname"},
    new { Name = "dateOfBirth"}
};

var InsertStatement = $"INSERT INTO {tableName} ({Join(cols, col => col.Name, ", ")})" 
    +  $"VALUES({Join(cols, col => $"@{col.Name}", ", ")})";
```